# Duplicate Question practice

Tags: discussion

Is it a bad practice of ask a question when the previous questions were not asked well and have no/good answer? 
There are several questions on Stack Overflow where the question marked as duplicate provides more insight either through question or answer!

Some real cases:-

[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867530/how-to-remove-duplicate-entries-from-a-mysql-db) asked a question which is not as well written and received as this question - [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685173/delete-all-duplicate-rows-except-for-one-in-mysql#comment5166734_4685173) which asks same question but asked later.

There were many use cases I saw while browsing site in real. I would come with better examples after some browsing. If we do some thought experiment, I guess this is possible indeed.

Comment: Can you link to some examples?

Comment: Sure, Give me sometime. It is not today or always. There are multiple times I have seen, but then I need to search to reproduce here. But such scenario could exist...

Comment: Please find examples to provide *before* you ask a question like this. A well-founded argument is important, just like research is important before asking any kind of question on the SE network. Your questions will be more well-received, then. =)

Comment: @J.Steen It will take sometime to produce such rare example, but with thought experiment such case could happen

Comment: The question is good this way. This prevents focusing on a question itself, instead of *your* question.

Comment: "Could" is rarely a reason to implement or change something unless you're a nuclear disaster prevention agency, but, fine. Discussion it is. I appreciate someone bringing this to light if it's really a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you (or someone else) already asked a question and you find a duplicate with bad answers, you can close the old one as duplicate of the newer one with better answers.

If you want to ask a new question, and the other one is an exact duplicate without good answers, add a bounty to the question instead of asking again.

Comment: So we can mark old one as duplicate instead of newer one? That is cool. However adding a bounty might not be possible all the time. But if what you said is an acceptable practice, then this solves my dilemma..!

Comment: Perfectly acceptable. Also keep in mind that the quality of questions can *change* over time. The specific case you speak of was back in 2011 and the closure was in 2012. A lot can happen in three years' time.

Comment: @CTRL-ALT-DELETE: Yes, that is okay. It doesn't harm anyone. It only makes the site better.

Comment: If noone finds the duplicate until it is answered *significantly better* than the older version, it gets to bethe master. Otherwise, it will just be closed, and if obvious downvoted.